# How can we create an UI interface for a Snowflake table to visualize its value / update?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I would like to create an Interface through which we can visualize data of a particular table (1 or 2 columns).
Cherry on the cake - If I could change the value (e.g TRUE <=> FALSE) from UI itself.

Comment: You can use [Dashboards](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-dashboards.html)

Comment: What's the issue with using the Snowflake WebUI?

Comment: @Sergiu and Nickw you both may be correct. I need to explore a bit more coz I am new to Snowflake. Thank You both!